# What is 'dangling vote' in the geth clique POA algorithm?

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, clique

I am reading the code implementation for clique POA algorithm(`consensus/clique`), and encountered this line of comment in `consensus/clique/snapshot.go`:

```golang
// uncast removes a previously cast vote from the tally.
func (s *Snapshot) uncast(address common.Address, authorize bool) bool {
    // If there's no tally, it's a dangling vote, just drop
    tally, ok := s.Tally[address]
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    (...)
}
```

What is this 'dangling vote'? In what case does dangling vote created?

Comment: I think it is an artifact of geth implementation, if you try to 'uncast' a vote for a proposal that was already dismissed. It should not happen.